# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined with Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular5, angular6

The value is diplayed on screen is correct but I get this error in the logs :*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*.

I tried several way with '?' like this :
`[(ngModel)]="customer?.name"` but not work then I need help :)

In the service :

```
  getCustomer(name:string){
    let url = `http://localhost:8081/api/customer/${name}`;

    return this.http.get<Customer>(url);
  }
```

In the .ts for the component :

```
customer: Customer;

this.customerService.getCustomer(this.pName)
      .subscribe(
        (data) =>{  
          this.customer = data['customer'];
        },
        err =>{
          console.log('getCustomer failed');
        }
    );
```

In the template :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="myname" required [(ngModel)]="customer.name" name="myname">
```

But that's not work.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: In your component ts file add `public customer = {}`;

Comment: I added a line of code I have already

Comment: does you `Customer` interface has name property? and can you verify that json from server also has `name` property?

Comment: When you say that `customer?.name` doesn't work, what do you mean? Does it still give you the same error, or a different error?

Comment: what do you see when you add a console.log(this.customer);

Answer (score 6):

Add default value

```
public customer = {} as Customer;
```

and 
this

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myname" required [(ngModel)]="customer?.name" name="myname">
```

Comment: public customer = {} as Customer; try this

Comment: I tried but I get this error (and the page is not displayed) compiler.js:1016 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 16 in [customer?.name=$event] in ng:///AppModule/CustomerEditComponent.html@7:80 ("Email4">name</label>

Comment: @Kris-I the error is in CustomerEditComponent can you show it's content?

Comment: It's the code you see in my initial post nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Giving an default value will fix this problem, not sure whats happening  your side, make sure you are not just defining but assigning to an empty object to it like this
public customer = {} as Customer;

Answer (score 0):

1. Import statements at top

   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

   2. Constructor

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   3. [(ngModel)]="customer?.name"
   4. Angular 6: Update your code as below

`getCustomer(name: string): Observable < any > {
        const url = http://localhost:8081/api/customer/${name};`

```
    return this.http.get(url)
        .pipe(map((response: any) => {
          return response.json();
    }));
}
```

Comment: not possible to adapt the current code without using Observable, map and so on ? and I got this error :return this.http.get<Customer>(url)
        .pipe(map((response: any) => {
          return response.json();
    }));

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if the customer is available with `ngIf`.

For example,

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="customer"  class="form-control" id="myname" required [(ngModel)]="customer.name" name="myname">
```

**OR**

You may need to define another variable and used it inside of `[(ngModel)]`

For example,

```
let customerName: string = '';
this.customerService.getCustomer(this.pName)
      .subscribe(
        (data) =>{  
           this.customerName = data.customer.name;
        },
        err =>{
          console.log('getCustomer failed');
        }
    );
```

In template:

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="customer"  class="form-control" id="myname" required [(ngModel)]="customerName" name="myname">
```